# Javascript mouseenter() not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm new to php and javascript, and I'm writing my first webpage program. I'm trying to add a login feature. The expected behavior is: whenever the mouse cursor is over the account icon, it will show the login option. Once the user logs in, and moves the cursor over the account icon again, it will show the profile option. However, the actual behavior is: once the user logs in, and moves the cursor over the account icon again, it doesn't show the profile option unless move the cursor exactly on the top/bottom border of account_icon. Seems like only the top and bottom border of account_icon can trigger the mouse event. I have to refresh the page (F5) and then it works properly.

I added "header("Location: index.php");" in order to refresh the page, but it still doesn't work. Only F5 can solve this problem. I googled a lot related issues and tried many things, but I still couldn't find a solution to fix this problem. I'm wondering if anyone could help me on this issue or give me any advises? I will really appreciate.

My code is listed as below. Please let me know if you need any more information.

**Php Code index.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_login']) && !empty($_POST['submit_login']))
{
    if($_POST['email_login'] && $_POST['password_login'])
    {
        $query = "SELECT user_id, email, password FROM user_login WHERE email='{$_POST['email_login']}' AND password='{$_POST['password_login']}'";

        if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($query_run) != NULL)
            {
                while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {
                    $user_id = $query_row['user_id'];
                    $email = $query_row['email'];
                    $password = $query_row['password'];

                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $query_row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $query_row['email'];
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $query_row['password'];

                    header("Location: index.php");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Can't find";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // the username or password is not filled in
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}

    <div id="account">
        <img id="account_icon" src="accountIcon.png" alt="account">
        <div class="account_infobox">
            <ul>
                <?php
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])):

                ?>
                <li class="account_info signin">
                    <a class="account_btn" id="signin_btn" href="javascript:void(0)">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="account_info signup">
                    <a class="account_btn" id="signup_btn" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Up</a>
                </li>

                <?php
                    else:
                ?>

                <li class="account_info profile">
                    <a class="account_btn" id="profile_btn" href="?profile">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="account_info signoff">
                    <a class="account_btn" id="signoff_btn" href="?logoff">Log Off</a>
                </li>

                <?php
                    endif;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#account_icon").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".account_infobox").slideDown(100);
    });

    $("#account").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".account_infobox").slideUp(100);
    });

    $("#signin_btn").click(function(){
        $(".login_dialog").show();
    });

    $("#signup_btn").click(function(){
        $(".signup_dialog").show();
    });
});
```

**CSS code**

```
#account {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    left: calc((100% - 1200px) / 2 + 1200px - 80px);
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;

    border: 2px solid yellow; /* Only use this border for layout debugging */
}

#account_icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 1100;
    border: 2px solid red; /* Only use this border for layout debugging */
}

.account_infobox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: calc((100% - 1200px) / 2 + 1200px - 200px);
    top: 53px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;    
    background: #333333;    
    border: 2px solid blue; /* Only use this border for layout debugging */
}
```

Comment: Did you try `hover` instead of `mouseleave` & `mouseenter` ?

Comment: Hi Shahsahebi, i tried hover and it's same thing. Once login, the event is only triggered when the cursor is placed exactly on top or bottom border of account image

Comment: The truth is unfortunately I can't imagine your problem, I don't have any mentality about what happen there

Answer (score 0):

That moment you give `header()` stop the execution to make it work:

```
while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
{
    $user_id = $query_row['user_id'];
    $email = $query_row['email'];
    $password = $query_row['password'];

    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $query_row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $query_row['email'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $query_row['password'];

    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
```

This way, it sends the headers and the browser refreshes page.

Comment: Thank you Kumar. I tried this too, but it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery , you need to use `hover` and `blur` event :

**Updated code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#account_icon").hover(function(){
        $(".account_infobox").slideDown(100);
    });

    $("#account").blur(function(){
        $(".account_infobox").slideUp(100);
    });

    $("#signin_btn").click(function(){
        $(".login_dialog").show();
    });

    $("#signup_btn").click(function(){
        $(".signup_dialog").show();
    });
});
```